# Is Google Maps really dropping support for the CHTMLView (IE) browser?

Tags: c++, google-maps, mfc

I have developed a Windows application using mfc and CHTMLView that displays maps using the Google Maps api.  Starting today (8/15/17) it is reporting that the api is no longer supported in this browser.  Does anyone have any additional info on this?  This will be a major hassle if I have to switch to Bing maps or something else because Google maps won't run with the integrated IE.

Comment: Which API?  https://developers.google.com/maps/maps-api-list   And supported browsers: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport  .

Comment: I get the message "You are using a browser that is not supported by the Google Maps JavaScript API.  Consider changing your browser."  This behavior just started today.

Comment: SOLVED:  I was using the meta tag in my html as such:

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

Now I added the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION registry entry and the problem is fixed.

Comment: Additionally I suggest to set [`FEATURE_GPU_RENDERING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330731(v=vs.85).aspx#gpu_rendering) to `1` to improve rendering performance.